# Ansible custom plugin

Tags: python, ansible

I have two dicts in my playbook and python fuction: ex.

```
mysql_dict_server1={"log":{"log_slow":"False"},"mysqldump":{"buffer":"10M","max_packet":"5M","uniq":"DO NOT DEL","change":"abc"}}`

mysql_dict_server2={"log":{"log_slow":"False/Chnaged"},"mysqldump":{"buffer":"10M","change":"cba","added":"TREUE"}}

def merge(a, b):
 for key in b:
  if key in a:
   if isinstance(a[key], dict) and isinstance(b[key], dict):
    merge(a[key], b[key])
   else:
    a[key] = b[key]
  else:
   a[key] = b[key]
 return a
```

So how i could write my custom module/plugin to pass `args(mysql_dict_serverX)` and get new result
as example:

```
- set_fact:
     merged: return value from fuction.
```

or use merged directly in my jinja2 template 
`{% for key,val in merged_server.items() %}`..... etc

Comment: solution found use dict1|combine(dict2,recursive=true)